# Not able to capture Debug mode using Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I'm getting strange behavior. Not able to capture DEBUG mode for specific logger.

Here is my Properties file

```
logfile=C:/Softwares/logFiles

log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, generalDebug, generalError

log4j.appender.generalDebug=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.generalDebug.File=${logfile}/debug.log
log4j.appender.generalDebug.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.generalDebug.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.generalDebug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.generalDebug.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d{ISO8601}|%r %C|%L|%x - %m%n
log4j.appender.generalDebug.Threshold=DEBUG

log4j.appender.generalError=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.generalError.File=${logfile}/error.log
log4j.appender.generalError.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.generalError.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.generalError.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.generalError.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d{ISO8601}|%r %C|%L|%x - %m%n
log4j.appender.generalError.Threshold=ERROR

#######################################################################

log4j.logger.JavaTest=ERROR, HipDebug, HipError
log4j.additivity.JavaTest=true

log4j.appender.HipDebug=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HipDebug.File=${logfile}/HipDebug.log
log4j.appender.HipDebug.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.HipDebug.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.HipDebug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HipDebug.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d{ISO8601}|%r %C|%L|%x - %m%n
log4j.appender.HipDebug.Threshold=DEBUG

log4j.appender.HipError=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HipError.File=${logfile}/HipError.log
log4j.appender.HipError.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.HipError.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.HipError.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HipError.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d{ISO8601}|%r %C|%L|%x - %m%n
log4j.appender.HipError.Threshold=ERROR
```

And In Project's package name `JavaTest`, Where I'm using below code snippet 
to get log.

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("C:\\Softwares\\ConfigFiles\\log4j.properties");         
   Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestClass.class);
   logger.log(TestClass.class.getCanonicalName(), Level.DEBUG, "I'm Writing for DEBUG Mode", null);
```

I want, when am running `DEBUG` mode, It should write only in `HipDebug.log` file. But if I use `ERROR` mode, its not writing in any file. (Should write only in `HipError.log` file)

Secondly, When I use `ERROR`, It writes to all four files. (`debug.error, error.log, HipDebug.log, HipError.log`) .Why is it so ?

When and how can I write to only rootLogger files ? (`error.log and debug.log files only`)

Can anyone Suggest please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I try to recreate what you're doing I do see that logs are not written, but this occurs when using DEBUG level to generate the log events, not ERROR. I have modified the quoted question below to reflect this.

> ...if I use [DEBUG] mode, its not writing in any
>   file.

The problem here is that your loggers are set to ERROR mode which means they will only accept events with level ERROR or FATAL. The logger and the appender must accept the event before the message is logged.

> Secondly, When I use ERROR, It writes to all four files. (debug.error,
>   error.log, HipDebug.log, HipError.log) .Why is it so ?

You have `log4j.additivity.JavaTest=true` which means any event accepted by the `JavaTest` logger will be sent to both its appenders and the appenders of its parent loggers (unless one of them breaks the chain by setting additivity false)

Also, since you have `log4j.appender.generalDebug.Threshold=DEBUG` and `log4j.appender.HipDebug.Threshold=DEBUG` these appenders will accept events of levels DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, and FATAL.

> When and how can I write to only rootLogger files ? (error.log and
>   debug.log files only)

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to ask here but you could send events to the root logger's appenders by getting the root logger and calling the appropriate methods on it.

One final thought - if at all possible you should migrate to [log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) as it offers many improvements over log4j1 and log4j1 has reached end of life.